# How to check the string doesn’t contain any letters in swift?

Tags: swift, string

i have trouble during making the letter checker, my code is like this: `if !containLetters(“1234h”){print(“pass”)}`

my function is

```swift
    func containsOnlyNum(input: String) -> Bool {
         var ok = false
         for chr in input {
             for check in "1234567890.-"{
                if chr == check{
                    ok = true
                }
             }
             if ok != true{
                 return false
             }
         }
         return true
    }
```

If I check for `“h”` then didn’t pass, but if i check for `”1h”` then it still pass! Please help me to fix this problem. I will give a big thank for anyone who helped me

Comment: Your checking is inverted. You are actually checking that at least one allowed character is in the string.
There are much easier way to do this, e.g. using a regular expression, but for the sake of learning you should probably fix this one first. Try to perform the algorithm manually on a paper, step by step, to see the problem.

Comment: actually, a dot (.) or minus symbol (-) can be passed the checking too,

Comment: Oh @Sulthan thank you for this helping, but how to make it???

Comment: So it might be check for the first letter first, cannot, then return false, can, then continue check. Is it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix the algorithm is this way:

```
func containsOnlyNum(input: String) -> Bool {
     // check every character
     for chr in input {
         var isNum = false
         
         for check in "1234567890.-"{
            if chr == check {
                isNum = true
                // if we have found a valid one, we can break the iteration
                break
            }
         }
         
         if !isNum {
             return false
         }
     }
    
     return true
}


print(containsOnlyNum(input: "1234")) // true
print(containsOnlyNum(input: "1234h")) // false
```

However, then you can directly simplify it to:

```
func containsOnlyNum(input: String) -> Bool {
    return input.allSatisfy { chr in
        "1234567890.-".contains(chr)
    }
}
```

which does exatly the same but uses `allSatisfy` and `contains` functions, which represent the logical operators `ALL` and `EXISTS`.

However, programmers normally use regular expressions for similar tasks:

```
func containsOnlyNum(input: String) -> Bool {
    return input.range(of: "^[0-9.\\-]+$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked successfully. Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooloo much!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: also, can you explain what is String.allStatisfy?

Comment: @YaleY The explanation is written below. It's the Swift way of saying "all characters in this string must satisfy the following condition".

Comment: Oh i can see it now, the browser just….

Answer (score 1):

You can check that a string contains only the characters you're interested in like this:

```
extension String {
    var containsOnlyNum: Bool {
        let wanted = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
            .union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-."))
        return unicodeScalars
            .allSatisfy(wanted.contains)
    }
}

"-12.34".containsOnlyNum  // true

"A1234".containsOnlyNum   // false
```

But if you are interested in numbers, then this is a problem:

```
"-12.-34.".containsOnlyNum  // true
```

Instead, you can just try casting the string to a double and see if it is a number or not

```
Double("1234") != nil // true, a number
Double("-1.234") != nil // true, a number


Double("A1234") != nil  // false, not a number
Double("-12.-34.") != nil  // false, not a number
```

Which is almost right unless you don't want this case:

```
Double("1234e2") != nil // true, a number
```

But you can use both checks if you don't want to allow that, or else if you are able to parse a Double from the input you can just do the cast.

Comment: It is also a good method too! And this helps more!